# Woocommerce display product variations

Tags: woocommerce

Im having a issue with function:

I need to display product variations (not parent) on category page. -

**Let's say:** 
If is category "t-shirts" I need to display all product variations with attribute "t-shirts".

Im using this function but it's not working:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'rc_modify_query_get_design_projects' );

 function rc_modify_query_get_design_projects( $product ) {

   if (is_tax('pa_tshirts') || is_tax('pa_shirts') || is_product_category('summer')) {

      $product->set('post_type', 'product_variation');

   }

 }
```

Hope anyone can help.
Thanks

Comment: is_tax() is for the Archive Page for that taxonomy.  Is there an archive page for "T-Shirts" ? Product Attribute is like color or size.

Comment: Here is actual page - displaying parent products,  not variations. https://woocommerce-224624-1066363.cloudwaysapps.com/sommer. As its german, I added "t-shirts" as an example. On that page in Breadcrumbs "wollbettdecke" is category and "sommer" is attribute listed as custom taxonomy I think. Only problem is that I need to display variations not parents. Thanks Ankush